# API URL for internal google earth enterprise

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My company has an internal google earth enterprise server. I can get to it via `http://local/default_map`

I like to switch from the public API server, `<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>`, to the internal one. 
But `http://local/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false` returns Forbidden error: You don't have permission to access /maps/api/js/ on this server.

How can I find out if the internal server supports the API feature and how to configure it?

Comment: Do you have permission to access that api on the local server?

Comment: If you have google earth enterprise you have paid google for help.